# C# - Move object from position to position in 3D dimension

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple C# console application which I use as TCP server for my Unity client. I need to translate from the starting x,y,z position to the end position and `Console.WriteLIne` all the x,y,z coordinates which it will take to reach the end position.

Here is the prototype function I have written to move the object from 3d position to another with a certain speed.

```
public class Position{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
}

public static Position MoveObject(Position position1, Position position2, float speed){
    Position currentPosition = new Position();
    currentPosition.x = position1.x + (position2.x - position1.x) * speed;
    currentPosition.y = position1.y + (position2.y - position1.y) * speed;
    currentPosition.z = position1.z + (position2.z - position1.z) * speed;
    return currentPosition;
}
```

However, this is just a prototype. I need something like `while` loop to loop thru every point the object will be until it reaches the end position and displays all the coordinates it needs to take.

**Please bear in mind that this is C# Console Application, not Unity project.**

Comment: I am not sure to understand completely.
What is your speed exactly? Here if I get it, it is the number of times it travels the distance between the two positions at each call of the function. Is it what you planned?

And also, as a number of point between two position is infinite, please be more specific there too

Comment: OP wants a smooth translation of his object over time.

Comment: @OP: Can you rephrase your question to be more precise please. As Dimitry mentioned, there is no valid answer to your question as the number of points is unlimited.

Comment: @DimitriBosteels `speed` i think should be the multipiler of the time to pass the distance faster when increased.

Answer (score 0):

you will want a variable for the the old position, and the desired position. and a timer, with a tick set to about 1500. then in your while loop you simply interpolate between them.

change ur class to:

```
public class Position{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
public Position(float ix, float iy, float iz){
this.x=ix;
this.y = iy;
this.z=iz;
}
}
```

something like :

```
Position oldPosition;//you need to set this to start position somewhere(OnStart or prior method)
Position newPosition;//you need to set this to desired position somewhere(OnStart or prior method)
```

and you will want this in Update()

```
if(currentPosition!=newPosition){
    Position distance = new Position(oldPosition.x-newPosition.x,oldPosition.y- 
    newPosition.y,oldPosition.z-newPosition.z,);
    Position currentPosition =new Position( distance.x/ (elapsedTime * 
    velocity),distance.y/ (Time.DeltaTime * velocity),distance.z/ (elapsedTime * 
    velocity));
}
```

so basically to step through in an update method, you need distance/(time*speed)
this is pseudo code but you should be able to work it out from here.

Comment: elapsedTime should be in milliseconds and velocity can be float?

Comment: Also oldPosition contains x,y,z. Can you edit your answer respecting that ?

Comment: You can't make Position - oldPosition.

Comment: you can not make Position - oldPosition because: Error operator "-" can not be applied to opperands of type "Position" and "Position". Please update your answer.

Comment: as I strictly pointed in my question you can't use any C# Unity functions such as `Time.DeltaTime`. It's a C# Console Application, not a Unity project. Also, I can not use `Update`, it's a Unity function.

Comment: why only `distance.y/ (Time.DeltaTime * velocity)` is on Time.DeltaTime and the others are on elapsed time. Can you please remove `Time.DeltaTime` from the answer and edit it so all Unity functions are remove and i can accept your answer after that.